# Commutative direct summands of C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I have a question about commutative direct summands of $C$*-algebras.

Let $A$ be a $C$*-algebra (with unit) and suppose that its bidual $A^{**}$ has a commutative direct summand, that is, $A^{**}=B\oplus C$ such that $B$ is non-zero and commutative. Does this force $A$ to have a non-zero commutative direct summand as well?

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the continuous functions $f$ from $[0,2]$ into $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $f(t)$ is diagonal for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Then $A$ has no commutative direct summand, but the atomic part of its bidual should be equal to the bounded functions $f$ from $[0,2]$ into $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $f(t)$ is diagonal for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, which contains plenty of commutative direct summands.

Comment: It is not clear to me that your description of the bidual is accurate since $C[0,1]^{**}$ is much larger than $\ell_\infty[0,1]$. Also, what is the gain of going from $C[0,1]$ to matrices?

Comment: The bidual of $C[0,1]$ is indeed much bigger, but its atomic part is $\ell_\infty[0,1]$. And the atomic part is a direct summand, so a direct summand of the atomic part is a direct summand of the bidual. I have to go to matrices in order to make sure that $A$ has no commutative direct summand; the problem with $C[0,1]$ is that it is commutative, so it has a commutative direct summand.

Comment: If you only require a complemented subalgebra then the diagonal matrices are such a summand too.

Comment: I assumed the original question referred to algebra direct summands.

Answer (score 4):

No. Take the algebra of continuous functions on some connected space so that it does not have non-trivial direct summands. On the other hand, in the second dual you will find minimal projections coming from point evaluations that give rise to non-trivial, one-dimensional summands.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Do you mean if the second dual has central atoms? How would you prove that?

Comment: @MarkRoelands, please see Section 3 here https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6hgd/preprints/Dissertatmeasurealgebrafinal.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiGpcj3lZzeAhXCsqQKHcwGAyEQFjABegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw217rPdjeFvFMtYqZRcpoIR

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question to only allowing a non-zero direct summand. Would that also be true in general?

Comment: @MarkRoelands, yes. Even more is true, please see Lemma 1 here: https://msp.org/pjm/1974/50-1/pjm-v50-n1-p11-s.pdf