# A characterisation of certain $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, jordan-algebras

I was wondering if there is a characterisation for $C^*$-algebras (unital) for which the bidual does not have any central atoms. It is not sufficient for example to demand that the $C^*$-algebra does not have a non-zero commutative algebra direct summand:

Consider the $C^*$-algebra 
$$
A:=\bigl\{f\in C([0,2];\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C}))\mid \ f \mbox{ is diagonal on } [0,1]\bigr\}.
$$
Then $A$ does not have a non-zero commutative algebra direct summand, but the atomic part of the bidual should be 
$$
A^{**}_\mathrm{atomic}=\bigl\{f\in\ell^\infty([0,2];\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{C}))\mid f \mbox{ is diagonal on } [0,1]\bigr\}
$$
which has plenty of central atoms. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313540/commutative-direct-summands-of-c-algebras).

It is true that the bidual of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ has no central atoms if and only if the state space $S(A)$ of $A$ has no singleton split faces. This is [Corollary 5.33 and Corollary 5.34](https://books.google.com/books/about/Geometry_of_State_Spaces_of_Operator_Alg.html?id=YBPSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA162) in *Geometry of State Spaces of Operator Algebras* by Alfsen and Shultz. This characterises these algebras in terms of the state space, but knowing a condition on $A$ would be very interesting.

Comment: Why the tag [tag:jordan-algebra] (a Jordan-algebra is a [non-necessarily-associative] commutative algebra satisfying the axiom $(xy)(xx)=x(y(xx))$)?

Comment: Because the self-adjoint part of a $C$*-algebra is a Jordan algebra (in fact it is a JB-algebra) with the product $x\circ y:=\frac{1}{2}(xy+yx)$.

Comment: OK thanks, but how is this connected to the question?

Comment: You could ask the same question for JB-algebras: Is there a characterisation for those JB-algebras that have no central projections in the bidual?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of condition you are looking for.  But if you just translate '$A^{* *}$ has a projection that is both central and minimal' into a statement about $A$ you obtain '$A$ has a one-dimensional quotient.'

Comment: @ Caleb Eckhardt. Do you mean to say that $A$ has no ideals of co-dimension one if and only if $A^{**}$ has no central atoms, because non-zero functionals always give you one-dimensional quotients?

Comment: @MarkRoelands Yes that is what I mean to say (unless you by 'atom' you mean something different than 'minimal projection'). Non-zero positive functionals won't give you a one-dimensional C*-algebra quotient unless those functionals happen to be multiplicative.